# Get only the Date and not the Day Date and Time for Yesterday and Tomorrow

Tags: javascript, date

I am looking to get yesterday and tomorrow's date but right now my code returns: "Wed Jun 26 2019 15:32:10 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" when I only want: "06/26/2019"

I currently have this issue for both yesterday and tomorrow. Here is the code I am using:

`var yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));
var tomorrow = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+1));`

Comment: getFullYear(), getMonth(), getDate()

Comment: But on the last day of the month will tomorrow's date have the correct month with these?

Comment: why not to try?

Comment: Actually your code returns a Date object. The output you see is what you get if you log a Date object without any other specific formatting instructions. The date is not stored in any specific human readable format, you're just seeing one way (the default way) it gets converted to a readable string. Use the functions of the Date object to get specific parts of the date as needed, or use a library such as momentJS (or others) which provide much more flexible formatting options and also easier ways to do calculations, addition, subtraction etc on dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to get yesterday:

```
let yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1));
let yesterdayFormatted =
  yesterday.getDate() +
  "/" +
  (yesterday.getMonth() + 1) +
  "/" +
  yesterday.getFullYear();
console.log(yesterdayFormatted);
```

And this for tommorow :)

```
let tommorow = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1));
let tommorowFormatted =
  tommorow.getDate() +
  "/" +
  (tommorow.getMonth() + 1) +
  "/" +
  tommorow.getFullYear();
console.log(tommorowFormatted);
```

Edit: Changed the "-" to your preferred "/".